# DrawRect on the Image in ios like below Image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, drawrect, quartz-2d

[image]

This is the Synch me app, what i want is I want to display the image as contact picture and Message like the below Transparent rectangle with text , I want to create the same rectangle with image with they have showed like Map,

Currently What I am doing is this -

[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

I just want to change the Image like first image,  My Message should come in this rectangle box and the below small image in like map image .

Here is my current code:

```
-(UIImage *) drawText:(NSString*) text inImage:(UIImage*)image :(UIImage *)contact_picture
{
    UILabel *lblText=[[UILabel alloc]init];


    lblText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];
    lblText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f];



    UIFont *font =lblText.font;;
    if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0), NO, 0.0f);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0));
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,320.0,480.0)];
    [contact_picture drawInRect:CGRectMake(230,295,90,90)];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20,120,320, 480);//Set Frame as per your Requirement
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);



    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: then what's your problem, just how to get the transparent black rectangle?

Comment: if so, using UIKit is easier as your last question. no need to use Quartz. just use a UILable and set its background color such as UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];

Comment: I want the same rectangle as in first image . how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the rectangle which shows "Jennifier checked in at....", you can use a UIView.

```
UIView *myRectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rectangleFrame];
[myRectangle setBackgroundColor:transparantColor];
myRectangle.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
[myRectangle.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

[yourSuperView addSubview:myRectangle];

//add your text view and image to myRectangle
```

---------------------Quartz version---------------------

draw a rectangle with corner radius, and fill it with transparent color.

below is code of drawing a rectangle with corner radius

```
- (void)rectangleInPath:(CGMutablePathRef)path WithWidth:(CGFloat)width Height:(CGFloat)height Radius:(CGFloat)radius Offset:(CGFloat)offset{

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, offset, offset+radius);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, offset, offset, offset+radius, offset, radius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, width-radius-offset, offset);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, width-offset, offset, width-offset, radius+offset, radius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, width-offset, height-radius-offset);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, width-offset, height-offset, width-radius-offset, height-offset, radius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, radius+offset, height-offset);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, offset, height-offset, offset, height-radius-offset, radius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, offset, offset+radius);
}
```

Comment: and still, actually no need deep into quartz. but add quartz code after seeing your comments in last question